# Decoding under the hood in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, decode

I am new to python and I am getting an error log of 'ascii codec can't decode byte ...'. The error is in line

```
status = task.status_text()
```

from code

```
text = u"*{username}* moved a `Task` on <{url}|Card {prefix}-{local_id}> to `{status}`".format(
        username = slack_util.user_name(user),
        url = url,
        prefix = project.prefix,
        local_id = story.local_id,
        status=task.status_text()
    )
```

and status_text function is this:

```
def status_text(self):
        si = self.status * 10 - 10
        ei = self.status * 10
        return self.story.project.task_status_names[si:ei].strip()
```

I know that there is some decoding is happening as it is given in error log. But I do not know where it is happening and why? My question is where decoding happening in this code? I am really stuck here.

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without knowing what `slack_util` and `project` and `story` and `task` are. Please see [mcve].

Comment: @Aran-Fey. Thanks for your comment. Python stack trace is showing error in line 'status = task.status_text()' and I have given relevant code for it. Isn't it sufficient?

Comment: If you're new to Python, is there a reason you're using Python 2.7 instead of 3.6?

Comment: yeah, company I am working with is using python2.7

Comment: Well, then the best you can do is subtly remind your boss that Python 2.7 will be abandoned by the Python developers in a year and a half, most major linux distros have switched to providing bare-minimum support for it, and many important packages have already dropped it, but, you know, no rush, your team has only had 8-1/2 years to prepare so far and gone 3 years past the original deadline, so I'm sure they can keep putting it off, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, whenever you mix a `unicode` and a `str` in the same expression, it has to `decode()` the `str` or `encode()` the `unicode` automatically to make them work. And it does this using your default encoding, which is usually `'ascii'`. So, if any of your strings aren't ASCII, you get an error like this.

One place this happens is when you call `format` on a `unicode` object and pass it a `str` value to be formatted:

```
>>> u'{}'.format('abc')
u'abc'
>>> u'{}'.format('abc\xe9')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And notice that you have a line just like this in your code. Obviously, that `task.status_text()` is returning a string that isn't ASCII, just like the `'abc\xe9'` in my simpler example.

---

To fix this, you either need to be careful to always use one type consistently:

```
>>> print '{}'.format('abc\xe9')
abcé
```

Ideally, you can configure your database interface to return `unicode` instead of encoded `str` in the first place:

```
>>> print u'{}'.format(u'abcé')
abcé
```

If not, you need to make the `decode` or `encode` explicit, so you can specify the right encoding:

```
>>> print u'{}'.format('abc\xe9'.decode('latin-1'))
abcé
```

Of course I have no idea where your `status_text` is coming from, so I have no idea whether it's Latin-1. (In fact, UTF-8 is probably more likely.) But you should know, or be able to look it up or otherwise find out.

---

If you think this is a huge pain… well, that's exactly why Python 3 was invented over a decade ago. All of these problems will go away as soon as you decide to upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Here I tried your code with the following input for generating the text format:

```
text = u"*{username}* moved a `Task` on <{url}|Card {prefix}-{local_id}> to `{status}`".format(
        username = 'rahul',
        url = 'www.google.com',
        prefix = 'Pro',
        local_id = '12',
        status='Hello'
    )
print text
```

And the output I got:

```
*rahul* moved a `Task` on <www.google.com|Card Pro-12> to `Hello`
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

That means the values returning by your variables inside the format method not as per these above I am passing.So, first try printing these fives variable what exactly they returning values.

Comment: As I have mentioned in question that I do not have information on data as this error is from log file. The only thing I know about data is that data stored in database is in unicode format.

Comment: @sourabh I understand your problem but at least you can print these variables value before passing in.SO, You can get some idea.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You don't have any non-ASCII characters in your example, so of course you don't reproduce the OP's problem. But… so what does that tell him?